# How to make a button that will display elapsed time on a page using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Looking to create a button that will display an alert showing the time spent on the current page.

i.e. You click the "click me" button, and it pops up an Alert with the total elapsed time on the page

So far I have this

```
<html>
  <body>


   <p> Total Elapsed Time on Page Button </p>


     <input type="button" value="click me" onclick="stopTime"()>


  </body>
</html>
```

Then my javascript is

```
function stopTime() {
    alert("Elapsed Time");
    var startDate = new Date();
    var startTime = startDate.getTime();
    var date_now = new Date (); 
    var time_now = date_now.getTime (); 
    var time_diff = time_now - startTime; 
    var seconds_elapsed = Math.floor ( time_diff / 1000 );


}
```

When I click the button, nothing happens.

What am I messing up? Thank you.

Comment: `onclick="stopTime"()` -> `onclick="stopTime()"` will fix the handling of the event

Comment: Welcome to SO! :)

Comment: Thank you for the welcoming! I love it so far --

I used your advice and that fixed the problem as well as the reply by MichaelvE, but the Alert doesnt give me the actual elapsed time, just the text "Elapsed Time"

How would I fix this?

Comment: Yeah I know. I think @poul-bak provides a good answer to this question with their latest edits.

Answer (score 2):

You need to keep your function brackets with in the quotes:

```js
var startDate;

function stopTime() {

  var startTime = startDate.getTime();
  var date_now = new Date();
  var time_now = date_now.getTime();
  var time_diff = time_now - startTime;
  var seconds_elapsed = Math.floor(time_diff / 1000);
  alert(seconds_elapsed+" seconds");
}

function start() {
  startDate = new Date();
}

window.onload = start();
```

```html
<p> Total Elapsed Time on Page Button </p>


<button onclick="stopTime()">click me</button>
```

Comment: This fixed my problem with nothing happening when clicking the button, however the text in the alert says "Elapsed Time" rather than the intended result of.. well the elapsed time on the page.

How do I do this? Thank you again for you help! I appreciate it very much.

Comment: You need to set the startDate on page load, then calculate once the button is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

You need a separate function to start time (currently you start the time and immidiately stops it).

```
var startDate = new Date();
var startTime = startDate.getTime();

function stopTime() {
    var date_now = new Date (); 
    var time_now = date_now.getTime (); 
    var time_diff = time_now - startTime; 
    var seconds_elapsed = Math.floor ( time_diff / 1000 );
    alert("Elapsed Time: " + seconds_elapsed + " seconds");
}
```

The code to start the time should be global.

Now you should get the elapsed time in seconds on your alert.

**Edit**:

Fixed typo, it should be 'seconds_elapsed'. Now it should Work.

Comment: This broke my alert, but interesting with the alert("Elapsed Time:" + seconds_elepsed + 'seconds'); I tried to add that to the working ones the other two replies left and this line broke the alert as well. 

Thanks for the reply though!

Comment: Hello! I tried the edit, and it fixed my issue with the broken button -- however, it gives me "Elapsed Time:seconds_elepsedseconds" in the prompt, rather than the desired "XY.ABC seconds have elapsed" I want. What am I missing? Seriously confused, thank you for your time and help!

Comment: Double check your quotes, it must be exactly as I wrote - 'seconds_elapsed' is a variable, that must be outside of the quotes.